# Qt/QML application crashes at start-up in Debug Mode

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm using Qt 5.3 mingw on windows and writing application with Qt/QML.
sometimes, a crash happens at start-up when I run the project in Debug mode and trying to debug the code.

> the inferior stopped because it received a signal from operating system

Is  there any problem with QML or something else?
the stack is like this when error happens.

```
0   QScopedPointer<QObjectData, QScopedPointerDeleter<QObjectData> >::data      143 0x9d2250c   
1   qGetPtrHelper<QScopedPointer<QObjectData> >     941 0x99e1cc7   
2   QOpenGLContext::d_func      148 0x9d21f9b   
3   QOpenGLContext::isValid     596 0x99e05d1   
4   GLAcquireContext::GLAcquireContext      75  0x1af7ec21  
5   QQuickContext2DTexture::paint       247 0x1aef2b79  
6   QQuickContext2DTexture::event       366 0x1aef34a1  
7   QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper      3500    0x217eded3  
8   QApplication::notify        2953    0x217eb985  
9   QCoreApplication::notifyInternal        935 0x6b929f96  
10  QCoreApplication::sendEvent     237 0x6b9cf2db  
11  QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents       1539    0x6b92b14e  
12  QEventDispatcherWin32::sendPostedEvents     1143    0x6b97b006  
13  qt_internal_proc(HWND__*, unsigned int, unsigned int, long)@16      421 0x6b978708  
14  gapfnScSendMessage  C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll      0x768362fa  
15  ??          0x2e07d2    
16  USER32!GetThreadDesktop C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll      0x76836d3a  
17  __lambda0::operator()       364 0x6b978443  
18  ??          0x2e07d2    
19  USER32!CharPrevW    C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll      0x768377c4  
20  USER32!DispatchMessageW C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll      0x7683788a  
21  QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents        756 0x6b979a0b  
22  QEventLoop::processEvents       136 0x6b92803c  
23  QEventLoop::exec        212 0x6b9282d7  
24  QThread::exec       511 0x6b795f49  
25  QThread::run        578 0x6b7960b1  
26  QThreadPrivate::start(void*)@4      407 0x6b798b3e  
27  msvcrt!_itow_s  C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll      0x76231287  
28  msvcrt!_endthreadex C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll      0x76231328  
29  KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk    C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll        0x76a233aa  
30  ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain   C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll       0x77079ef2  
31  ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain   C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll       0x77079ec5  
32  ??
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a guess: A QScopedPointer gets invalid as soon as we leave the scope. Ensure the pointer is valid whenever you access it!

Comment: The usage of QScopedPointer is within Qt codes and I am not accessing it anywhere. I guess something is wrong with loading QML components.

Comment: Post the code where you load your QML document.  Or is this is a pure QML application?

Comment: No this not a pure QML application.

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: If you don't want to share the code, try to make an example project that still reproduces this crash

Comment: The code is huge and the problem is that I don't know where it initiates to share it!!! I created this thread to see if anybody else have experienced this type of crush in QML or not and get guide.